# Development with firestore-stripe-payments installed locally

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I just installed `stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` from the Firebase console. The installation was successful and I can see the functions installed in the `functions` page in the console.

Is there a way to fetch these functions (along with other installed elements) locally using the Firebase CLI?

My goal is to have my remote configuration locally so I can use emulators during development.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI doesn't have a way to download deployed functions, and the
Firebase Console doesn't contain the data. BUT given that Firebase functions are on top of cloud functions we can get the source via the cloud console.

Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/, navigate to Cloud Functions and you can view the source of your deployed functions there. Once you have the source you can add it to your functions definitions locally and run locally (copy and paste) or deploy to another project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the directives. Unfortunately it seems that trying to run `firestore-stripe-payments` locally is quite difficult, I was able to run the functions and trigger `createCheckoutSession` but then It seems that we need to create "webhooks" for Stripe to communicate with Firebase. I just wonder how do people create a local testing environment when they want to integrate Stripe into their applications..

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Stripe integration but you may be able to mock these functions in your local environment to return a value adequate for testing.